# Not able to send correct ajax param data (using jquery-in-place-editor)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using  jquery-in-place-editor for in-place updating a field.

the html markup for this is

```
<span class="profile-txt" id="editme1"><?php echo $_SESSION['pupil_postcode']; ?></span>
```

and the jquery used is

```
$("#editme1").editInPlace({
    value_required: true,
    url: "editPupil.php",
    params:"postcode="+$("#editme1").html(),
    success: function(responseText){
        alert(responseText);
        //if(responseText=="Invalid Postcode"){
            //alert(responseText);
            //document.getElementById("editme1").innerHTML=postcode;
        //}
    }     
});
```

whenever I edit and enter the new value the ajax parameter still has the older values.
for example
the default value is ka10 7dw, if I change this to KA10 6DB, then also the postcode param takes the older value.

Comment: you could try using `$("#editme1").val()` instead of `$("#editme1").html()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, and from this, just modify the code to suit yours.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#editme1').editInPlace({
    url: 'editPupil.php',
    field_type: 'text',
  });
});
```

And put in the `editPupil.php`:

```
echo $_POST['update_value'];
```